# Using -rich suffix

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, suffixes, compounds

I have to following example phrase:

> A movie, rich with effects

Now I'd like transform it using the "-rich" suffix:

> Effect-rich movie

At first, does such phrase sound natural? If no, is there any alternative shortening, meaning the same? If yes, is it correct to say "effect-rich" or "effects-rich"?

EDIT: Seems, that both of these expressions ("effect rich" and "effects rich") are quite rare (< `1e-6 %`), according to Google Ngrams. However I don't understand what's the problem there. Is the "-rich" suffix always used with some physical matter (for example, "protein-rich foods")?

Comment: What results do you get with a suitable online search? I'd suggest Googling for "an effect rich" and "an effects rich". Which is more common? The ratio being? Is either phrase reasonably common? Can you find either in a dictionary?

Comment: The productivity of affixation is often illogical and unpredictable. [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/rich_2) has '-rich: used with **some** nouns to make adjectives describing what something contains or has in large amounts' The fact that effect-rich and effects-rich _are_ used shows that they're not considered unacceptable by everybody; the fact that they seem to be rarely used should however urge caution. Since they're transparent and would be used in an informal register, I can't see much problem in using them; I'd go with the one more common on Google.

Comment: In answer to your question about whether physical matter is necessary to support a "-rich" suffix, I think the answer is clearly no. I can imagine someone referring to "an idea-rich presentation," meaning "a presentation rich in ideas." What I find interesting is that I would use "idea-rich" there but "effects-rich" in connection with a movie rich in special effects. What I can't answer—and what makes your question interesting to me—is why I might prefer the singular-rich form in one case and the plural-rich form in the other.

Comment: [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-chinese-traditional/rich_7) certainly gives the physical-matter restriction: containing a large amount of a valuable substance. However, usage seems to be broadening: "a health-rich environment"  seems common among the 10,400 results for "a health rich".

Comment: Military people refer to a "target-rich environment".

Comment: Also, "tradition-rich" seems to be a fairly common compound adjective.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for pointing out those examples

Comment: @SvenYargs Well, talking about singular vs plural, I think that there should be such form, that is more likely to be understood as uncountable matter (though not material in my case), however I don't know exactly what it should be, though "effects-rich" sounds more natural to me. Anyway, it seems that the phrase "effects-rich movie" sounds a bit odd to an English speaker, doesn't it?

Comment: The OED has examples of _rich_ being used in descriptions "of non-material things" going back to 1290 ("þe Ioye of heouene þat so riche was and is") and 1330 ("Arthour þouȝt gode afin Þe riche conseyl of Merlin"). I didn't think that instances where "-rich" is linked to the nonmaterial thing were a recent innovation. Nevertheless, the Cambridge citation that Edwin Ashworth provides is not to be taken lightly, and a quick Google Books searches for "dream-rich" and "fantasy-rich" turn up first occurrence dates of 1969 and 1949, respectively—not so very long ago.

Comment: @SvenYargs What do you think about "effects-saturated movie" in terms of clearness and overall correctness in comparison with "effects-rich movie"?

Comment: I would understand "effects-saturated" to be somewhat less flattering than "effects-rich," since _saturated_ describes a thing so laden with a particular entity (here, effects) that it can't hold any more, whereas _rich_ implies "made more valuable [by]." Both terms sound natural to me, however; it's just that they don't have the same connotations.

Comment: **effects-laden** seems to be the more common phrase.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, didn't know about such expression...